# How to break number range to individual numbers oracle

Tags: oracle, numbers, range

How to break number range to individual numbers oracle

I have following number ranges in my table

| START_SN | END_SN |
| --- | --- |
| 850000 | 850003 |
| 850015 | 850017 |

And need following result.

| SN |
| --- |
| 850000 |
| 850001 |
| 850002 |
| 850003 |
| 850015 |
| 850016 |
| 850017 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample table:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM number_ranges;

  START_SN     END_SN
---------- ----------
    850000     850003
    850015     850017
```

This is one option which returns desired result (and avoids **duplicates**):

```
SQL>   SELECT start_sn + COLUMN_VALUE - 1 AS sn
  2      FROM number_ranges
  3           CROSS JOIN
  4           TABLE (
  5              CAST (
  6                 MULTISET (    SELECT LEVEL
  7                                 FROM DUAL
  8                           CONNECT BY LEVEL <= end_sn - start_sn + 1) AS SYS.odcinumberlist))
  9  ORDER BY sn;

        SN
----------
    850000
    850001
    850002
    850003
    850015
    850016
    850017

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

To break a number range into individual numbers in Oracle, you can use a combination of techniques such as subqueries, joins, and the CONNECT BY LEVEL clause. Here's an example query that achieves the desired result:

```
WITH number_ranges AS (
  SELECT 850000 AS start_sn, 850003 AS end_sn FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 850015 AS start_sn, 850017 AS end_sn FROM dual
)
SELECT start_sn + LEVEL - 1 AS sn
FROM number_ranges
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (end_sn - start_sn + 1)
ORDER BY sn;
```

Modifications:
The `number_ranges` subquery is used to represent your table data. You can replace it with your actual table name.

Comment: Did you test it? Does it really return *desired result*?

Comment: It will blow up the data because each iteration loops over the entire dataset.

Comment: Several of your recent answers appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.